# Mostrar solamente los archivos creados o modificados en una fecha ingresada

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Necesito ayuda: Deseo mostrar en un GridView solamente los archivos creados o modificados en una fecha ingresada en un textbox.

Tengo mi pagina así, donde muestro todos los archivos de la carpeta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo muestro solamente los archivos que han sido creados o modificados en la fecha ingresada en el textbox?

Mi código actual es el siguiente:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr;

dt.Columns.Add("fileName");
dt.Columns.Add("dateModified");

foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    DateTime dti = File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["fileName"] = Path.GetFileName(filePath).ToString();
    dr["dateModified"] = dti;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

grvFiles.Visible = true;
grvFiles.DataSource = dt;
grvFiles.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es crearte dos variables fechas, las misma contendrán la fecha seleccionada solo que una empezara desde la hora cero y la otra llegara hasta la última hora del día (incluyendo los minutos y segundos).

Dentro del bucle solo comparas si la fecha está dentro del rango del día.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr;

dt.Columns.Add("fileName");
dt.Columns.Add("dateModified");

CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

DateTime dateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFilter.Text, dateFormat, provider);
DateTime dateTo = new DateTime(dateFrom.Year, dateFrom.Month, dateFrom.Day, 23, 59, 59);

foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    DateTime dti = File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath);

    if(dti >= dateFrom && dti <= dateTo)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["fileName"] = Path.GetFileName(filePath).ToString();
        dr["dateModified"] = dti;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}

grvFiles.Visible = true;
grvFiles.DataSource = dt;
grvFiles.DataBind();
```

> Solo debes de reemplazar el formato de la fecha, si utilizas uno en específico y agregar la referencia: `using System.Globalization` para el proveedor de cultura.

También puede utilizar la propiedad [`Date`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.8) del `dti` y comparar directamente con la variable `dateFrom`.

```
if(dti.Date == dateFrom)
{
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["fileName"] = Path.GetFileName(filePath).ToString();
    dr["dateModified"] = dti;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

> Para esta opción o forma no se utiliza `dateTo`.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta este código para filtrar antes de llenar tu table cambia el txtDate por el nombre de tu control que almacena la fecha.

```
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\oaguilera\Desktop\Hyundai Transys Documents\Personal\Nominas");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;

    dt.Columns.Add("fileName");
    dt.Columns.Add("dateModified");

    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        DateTime dti = File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["fileName"] = Path.GetFileName(filePath).ToString();
        dr["dateModified"] = dti;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    //dt.rowFil = "dateModified= '" + [txtDate].value + "'";
    if(txtFilter.Text!="")
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "dateModified > '" + txtFilter.Text + " 00:00:00'";

    grvFiles.Visible = true;
    grvFiles.DataSource = dt;
    grvFiles.DataBind();
```

Comment: Agregué esto: 
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.RowFilter = "dateModified= '" + [txtFecha].value + "'";

Pero muestra el error: "El término de expresión '[' no es válido"

Comment: Christian no uses los [] <- los use solo como referencia de que eso debía ser modifiado por ti, inténtalo de nuevo eliminando eso y dame un feedback por favor.

Comment: Textbox no contiene una definición para "value"

Comment: Cambia el .value por .Text

Comment: Ya lo hice pero no muestra el gridview

Comment: Favor de leer nuevamente el código ha sufrido alguno cambios, verifica que la manera en que colocas la fecha coincida con la manera en que se ve en el gridview seguimos en contacto.

Comment: De esa manera tendría que siempre utilizar dos fechas... Cómo puedo obtener solo la fecha de creación o modificación del archivo?

Answer (score 0):

Yo, haria esto, lo más versatil.

Esto aceptaría las fechas usando guiones `-` o slash `/`.

```
bool parsed = false;
DateTime DateTimeOut = new DateTime();
string dateTimeString = textFilter.Text.Replace("/","-");
        if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, out dateTimeOut))
{
if (textFilter.Text.Contains("-"))
   dateTimeString =  textFilter.Text.Replace("-", "/");
   parsed=true;
}         
      

   string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;
    
    dt.Columns.Add("fileName");
    dt.Columns.Add("dateModified");
    
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        DateTime dti = File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath);
    if (parsed && dateTimeString == dti.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy))
        {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["fileName"] = Path.GetFileName(filePath).ToString();
        dr["dateModified"] = dti;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
    
    grvFiles.Visible = true;
    grvFiles.DataSource = dt;
    grvFiles.DataBind();
```